# Orient distinct incorrect

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I have the following output

```
orientdb {db=dict}> select count(distinct(pos)) from Synset;

----+------+-----
#   |@CLASS|count
----+------+-----
0   |null  |4    
----+------+-----

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 2.514 sec(s).
orientdb {db=dict}> select distinct(pos) from Synset;       

----+------+--------
#   |@CLASS|distinct
----+------+--------
0   |null  |n       
----+------+--------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.012 sec(s).
```

What am I doing wrong?
(the count of distinct values does not matches the select of this values. Actually there are 4 distinct values in db)

**UPDATE [WTF]**

```
orientdb {db=dict}> select * from (select distinct(pos) from Synset)

----+------+--------
#   |@CLASS|distinct
----+------+--------
0   |null  |n       
1   |null  |v       
2   |null  |a       
3   |null  |r       
----+------+--------

4 item(s) found. Query executed in 2.722 sec(s).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:`select distinct(pos) from Synset limit-1`

The console and the studio adds the `limit 20` automatically. So when you execute `select distinct(pos) from Synset` you actually returning the distinct values from the first 20 rows.

Now this `select * from (select distinct(pos) from Synset)` returns the expected result because the inner query doesn't have a limit, only the parent query have a limit of 20 but only have 4 results.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer. Now it is clear for me.

Comment: That is not really related to question, but I try to do "SELECT distinct json.param1, json.param2". If I do this, it will only show json.param2 in response, if I do "SELECT DISTINCT(json.param1, json.param2)" it returns error. Where json is a field/column in a table and param1/2 are parameters inside it.